# Bootstrap typeahead not showing(using static source)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm using bootstrap version 2.3.2. My question is, why when i type something it not show anything? Even though i'm using static source. Can someone explain to me what is wrong with my code? Thank you.

```
<input type="text" class="span3" data-provide="typeahead" id="typeahead">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#typeahead').typeahead({
      source: ["Ayam", "Kambing", "Itik"]
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you got any error in the JS console ?

Comment: Did you added bootstrap css file also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test using the CDN and see if it works. Replace your `bootstrap.js` with this.

```
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

If it still doesn't work, try using the `data-source` attribute.

It works in jsbin: http://jsbin.com/EYutuqU/1/edit

Comment: Thank you @JofryHS. I'm using your code and yes it working. Then switch back with my own code and save..it also working. I don't have idea how suddenly it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uhjxz/) to show you there's no problem.

Check your JS Console to see if you've got this error :

> Object [object Object] has no method 'typeahead'

If you find it, fix your `bootstrap.js` path.
You should also link `bootstrap.css`, but I assume you already did it.

Comment: Thank you @zessx. I don't know why how it suddenly work. I try using JofryHS method and yes it working. Then i undo to get my current code and save..pufff!! It working